# References for listings of point group operations

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, crystals

I am looking for a listing of the operations of point groups (preferrably as matrices). Nearly every textbook lists the irreducible representations and characters of the groups, but I have not found any that lists the specific operations. As an example, I am looking for the operations of the operations of the point group $m\bar{3}m$.

Alternatively: Is there a way I can compute these operations using a computer?

Comment: I don’t think you will not find these in terms of matrices since these are basis dependent and take huge amounts of space.